# Why don't called processRequest(request,response) directly in service(request,response)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring MVC,i had watch the code about `FrameworkServlet`. `FrameworkServlet`  extends `HttpServletBean`. `HttpServletBean` extends `HttpServlet`. The `FrameworkServlet` overrides the `service()` method in `HttpServlet`. What confuses me is why the `processRequest()` method is not called directly in `service()` method. Because i saw such as `doPost()`, `doGet()` is uses `processRequest()`.

I am grateful for any anwsers.

```
   /**
     * Override the parent class implementation in order to intercept PATCH requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpMethod httpMethod = 
                HttpMethod.resolve(request.getMethod());
        if (HttpMethod.PATCH == httpMethod || httpMethod == null) {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }
        else {
            super.service(request, response);
        }
    }
```

why not

```
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);

    }
```

if don't use delegate by `HttpServlet` to process the request, only use `processRequest()` in `FrameworkSevlet`,what will bad things happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `HttpServlet` is implemented with HTTP 1.1 in mind which does not support HTTP `PATCH` , so Spring implements the logic to handle `PATCH` request in `FrameworkServlet` by simply extending `HttpServlet`.

For the non `PATCH` request , simply delegate to the `HttpServlet` to handle. For `PATCH` request , handle by `FrameworkServlet` itself. So that if-then-else block in `FrameworkServlet` for checking if the request is `PATCH` is necessary.

Comment: if don't need delegate by `HttpServlet`,all request handle by `FrameworkServlet` use the `processRequest()`,will bad things happen?

Comment: Maybe because you skip some codes/logic that is supposed to be run in the HttpServlet.   But from what I see in the current latest version of source codes, it should be rather safe if skip HttpServlet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and solved my confusion.

Comment: Glad to hear , so consider to accept my answer or give me a vote up ? 